# Jinja conditional statement (if/else) and {{ py model outputs }}

Tags: python, html, conditional-statements, jinja2

I have a Flask application within **app.py** that contains 2 regression models and a call to an HTML template, **result.html**.

I would like each of the numeric predictions (=price and =avgprofit) generated by user input to my Flask application to change color based on which prediction value is greater (i.e., if price > avgprofit for a given input, the numeric price output value turns green).

In app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pickle
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('result.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def get_price():
    if request.method=='POST':
        result=request.form
        size = result['size']
        condition = result['condition']

        pkl_file = open('cat', 'rb')
        index_dict = pickle.load(pkl_file)
        cat_vector = np.zeros(len(index_dict))

        try:
            cat_vector[index_dict['size_'+str(brand)]] = 1
        except:
            pass
        try:
            cat_vector[index_dict['condition_'+str(condition)]] = 1
        except:
            pass

        pkl_file = open('model.pkl', 'rb')
        model = pickle.load(pkl_file)
        price = model.predict(cat_vector.reshape(1, -1))

        logpkl_file = open('logmodel.pkl', 'rb')
        logmodel = pickle.load(logpkl_file)
        avgprofit = logmodel.predict(cat_vector.reshape(1, -1))

        return render_template('result.html', price=price, avgprofit=avgprofit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And in result.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form action = "/reSale" method="POST">
    <p> Select Condition :   
        <select name="condition">
          <option value="new">New </option>
          <option value="used">Used </option>
    </select>

    <p> Select Size :
    <select name="size">
        <option value="small">Small </option>
        <option value="large">Large </option>
    </select>

    <p> <input type ="submit" value="submit" /> </p>

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xl btn-light mr-4">Price prediction: ${{ price }}</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xl btn-dark">Historic profit prediction: ${{ avgprofit }}</a>

      {% if {{ price }} > {{ avgprofit }} %}
      <span style="background-color:green;color:white;">Score</span>
      {% else %}
      <span>Score</span>
      {% endif %}

</body>
</html
```

My jinja error reads:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

My question is, how does one format a dynamically changing output in the HTML to change based on a conditional statement?

Comment: If you're inside `{% %}` brackets, you don't need `{{ }}` for variables.  Try `{% if price > avgprofit %}`.

Comment: I thought that might be it, but no- I get an error telling me that price is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{` and `}}` is for *printing* only. Simply use

```
{% if price > avgprofit  %}
```

Update: You also seem to have a duplicate definition of a GET request to the same URL (`/`). Make the following changes:

```
def home():
    return render_template('result.html', price=0, avgprofit=0)
```

and modify `get_price` to handle POST method only (as GET is already handled by `home`):

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_price():
```

Comment: Ah, I thought so too, but unfortunately I get an error that price is not defined. I...don't think I can define it in the HTML file...?

Comment: That's because you don't pass either `price` or `avgprofit` to the template in your `home` view. Why does that view use the same template?

Comment: I'd like the user to be able to submit different input values for size and condition in their respective dropdown menus without having to endlessly click and reclick the back button. So instead I have the home template regenerate new predictions based on those changed inputs while keeping the user on the same page.

Comment: Where does the user submit those values? You don't have a form in your template. If you want to reuse the same template you will need to pass empty values (such as `, price=None, avgprofit=None`) in your `home` view.

Comment: Edited to include the sections with user input and submit options. Apologies, I didn't include them thinking they weren't directly relevant to the formatting issue- I'm quite new at this. I'm not sure what you mean by passing the template empty values- they just show up as text, which means I'm doing something very wrong...

Comment: That's difficult to explain in a comment box; see my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent, your fix above worked- the word "Score" was changed to green when the condition specified was met, with those suggested edits.

Comment: Also- thank you!! This was fun to learn and I'm seeing a few weaknesses I didn't recognize before.